# Lax equivalence theorem for integro-differential equation

Tags: discretization, integral-equations

Can the Lax equivalence theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax_equivalence_theorem) be applied to the discretization of integro-differential equations, or does a similar theorem exist for them?